Question about Graph Theory: Proving Minimum Triangulation Vertices Estimate
If there is someone who is well versed in graph theory and topology, I would be very grateful for help!
Prove that the minimum number of triangulation vertices satisfies
meets the following estimate:
$$o(M) \ge 
\frac{7+\sqrt{49-24\pi(M)}}{2}$$
This problem deals with the topic "Pontryagin-Kuratovsky graphs".
$\pi(M)$ is the Euler characteristic of the surface M.
$$\pi(M) = o(M) - s(M) + f(M)$$
Where:
o(M) = number of vertices of triangles
s(M) = number of edges of triangles
f(M) = - number of triangles
The triangulation is the division of a surface into curvilinear triangles in such a way that
any pair of triangles intersect either at a vertex, along an edge, or do not intersect.
I would be grateful for any help!

$\sqrt{49}$ seems like a strange way to say $7$. Typo?

@GerryMyerson Oh yeah, thank you so much for noticing! The square root of 49 - 24()
